# Get singular variable or degree rotation from RotationMatrix.getValues()

Tags: android, graphics, matrix, rotation, rotational-matrices

I am using this tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/ Which gives me a rotating dialer based on an image view. However I am trying to extend it by adding functionality. In order to add this functionality however, I need to get the current clicked position. However, since it uses a rotationMatrix to rotate the imageview, I cannot get a singular position to analyze where the user clicks. Is there a way to crunch the 9 values found in a rotation matrix into one variable which indicates where the user touches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a computer graphics question than it is an Android question. Using [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates#Use_in_computer_graphics), a clockwise rotation about the origin would be represented as (I'm using Octave / MATLAB notation here to express this):

```
rotationMatrix = [ cos(theta) sin(theta) 0; -sin(theta) cos(theta) 0; 0 0 1 ]
```

Assuming that the matrix is just doing a rotation about the origin, you can call `java.lang.Math.acos` and pass in the first value in the array returned by `Matrix.getValues` to get your theta. That value is in radians, so if you want degrees you'll need to [convert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radians#Conversion_between_radians_and_degrees) it.

OTOH, depending on what you are doing you might just want to call `Matrix.invert` to obtain the inverse and multiply the point containing the touch coordinates with that inverse `Matrix` to "undo" the transformations.